# Unable to click Excel's button after running a form

Tags: vba, excel

First I run:

```
Sub ShowForm1()
   form1.Show
end sub
```

then form1 pops up

After that, I click at image1 (on form1) so the following code is run:

```
Private Sub image1_Click()
    Unload Me
    form2.Show
End Sub
```

then form2 pops up

On form2 I click on cancelButton so the following code is run:

```
Private Sub cancelButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

After that, I am unable to click on any cell of the worksheet. Actually, after running this code I am unable to click at any excel button at all (Save, File, Home)

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

I am using Excel 2013 and this code is running on an add-in.

Note: Running the below code

```
Sub ShowForm2()
   form2.Show
end sub
```

and clicking on the cancelButton afterward doesn't cause this problem to happen.

Comment: How do you trigger `ShowForm1` - from a ribbon button?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line after unloading the form.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing a debug stopper on the unload me and stepping through with key F8 to see what happens when you reach this point in the code?

The reason I ask is I had the exact same problem and forgot that I had some code tied to the **UserForm_Terminate()** event that was causing the userform to still appear in the background (invisible). I was messing around with "**EnableWindow Application.hWnd**" and I needed to make sure I shut the userform down a specific way in order not to "freeze" the screen.